# Convhull in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convex-hull

I have 3 vectors of position data : `x`, `y` and `z`

```
x = [0.1524 0.1219 0.0610 0.0914 0.0610 0.1219 0.0305 0.0914 0.2134 0.0610 0.1219
0.0305 0.0610 0.1219 0.0914 0.1524 0.0610 0.1524 0.0610 0.0610 0.0610 0.0610
0.1524 0.0914 0.0610 0.1524 0.0610 0.2134 0.0610 0.0914 0.1524];

y = [0.1219 0.1524 0.0305 0.1219 0.1524 0.1524 0.0610 0.1219 0.1219 0.1524 0.1524
0.0610 0.0914 0.1524 0.1829 0.1829 0.0914 0.1829 0.2134 0.0914 0.2134 0.0914
0.1829 0.0610 0.0914 0.1829 0.0914 0.1829 0.2134 0.1219 0.1829];

z = [0.0305 0.0305 0.0610 0.0610 0.0610 0.0610 0.0914 0.0914 0.0914 0.0914 0.0914
0.1219 0.1219 0.1219 0.1219 0.1219 0.1524 0.1524 0.1524 0.1829 0.1829 0.2134
0.2134 0.2438 0.2438 0.2438 0.2743 0.2743 0.2743 0.3048 0.3048];
```

I was wondering how I could apply convex-hull on this set? Matlab doesn't
accept this format but regularly spaced grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`convhulln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html) to compute the convex hull for dimensions grater than 2. If you want to plot the results, use [`trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html). See the sample code for your input below:

```
X = [x;y;z]'; %# involves a 3D point on each row  
K = convhulln(X);
trisurf(K,X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. I may sound stupid here but is there a way of knowing how many holes are within this shape. I mean looking at matlab's example for 2D, the heart shaped points are represented by a diamond shape object after using "convhull". So one could find the proportion of heart cells (nodes) to the total area of the convex hull, or in 3D of the total volume?

Comment: It is better that you ask this as a separate question.