# number of holes in convex hull in matlab

Tags: matlab, volume, convex-hull

I have used convhulln in matlab to find the surrounding shape of a set of data points in 3D. See history in:
[Convhull in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247475/convhull-in-matlab).
A good samaritan helped me to find out how it works in matlab. I need to know the propertion of gaps (holes) inside the 3D volume to the total volume of the convex hull. Is this possible?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, I would try this:

- find the convex hull of your set of points, which I will call S, using `convhull`
- find the convex hull of the set S', where

  ```
  S' := S - points_defining_the_convex_hull(S)
  ```

  (i.e., S' contains the points of S which do not *"enlarge"* its convex hull, thus the ones which are inside the convex hull itself.)
- make the difference/proportion between the volumes of S and S' (trivial, both are convex).

There is a strong assumption on the topology of the hole considered, i.e.

```
"the convex hull of the S' is the hole".
```

If you have a more complex topology of holes you can't avoid making active use of it (my guess, of course).

Comment: @user1641496, if this is good for you, you may want to consider to accept the answer; thanks.